# Xubuntu 14.10 on VirtualBox -- won't start or install

Tags: xubuntu, virtualbox

I'm trying to install Xubuntu 14.10 (tried 15.04 beta1 as well) in a VirtualBox (4.3.24) VM. The VM boots from the ISO, and when I let it boot to the live mode or select "install", it tries to come up into the graphical installer and hangs with a resized window which is long and narrow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2250037 solution worked for me.

Preferences + efi.

Some vdi images can also be downloaded, but that bybass the difficulty.

http://www.osboxes.org/xubuntu-14-10-images-released-vmware-virtualbox/

Comment: Thanks Bummi. The answer it indeed copied also, but may be to short. 

Before starting your virtual machine, in "Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager" go to File->Preferences.
In the dialogue that appears, select Display and then set "Maximum Guest Screen Size" to "None".
Press OK and then launch your virtual machine.

Also seems to require "Enable EFI"